# Небольшая проблемка с telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Проблема в том, что при вызове
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True) во второй раз - бот не реагирует на нажатие кнопки, код на которую я написал.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('-')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    itemNoBut = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Нет', callback_data='No1')
    itemYesBut = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Да', callback_data='Yes1')
    markup.add(itemYesBut, itemNoBut)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Здравствуйте, вас приветствует Restaurant Practice Bot</b>', parse_mode='html')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Наш ресторан имеет больше 1000 положительных отзывов, и мы рады видеть вас здесь. ', parse_mode='html')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Скажите, желаете ли вы сделать <i>заказ?</i>', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'Yes1':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
            itemFirstBut = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Первое блюдо ', callback_data='1Dish')
            itemSecondBut = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Второе блюдо ', callback_data='2Dish')
            itemDrinksBut = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Напитки ☕️', callback_data='Drinks')
            itemBackBut = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Я передумал..', callback_data='Back')
            markup.add(itemFirstBut, itemSecondBut, itemDrinksBut, itemBackBut)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Тогда давайте выбирать!', reply_markup=markup)
        if call.data == 'No1':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, ':(')

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback_choice(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == '1Dish':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
            itemSup1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Том Ям', callback_data='Tom Yan')
            itemSup2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Ливанский суп', callback_data='Livanskie')
            itemSup3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Тыквенный суп', callback_data='Tikveniy')
            itemSup4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Борщ с говядиной', callback_data='Borch')
            itemSup5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Фо Бо', callback_data='Fo Bo')
            markup.add(itemSup1, itemSup2, itemSup3, itemSup4, itemSup5)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Что именно мы будем?')
```

Comment: Заметил ошибку: в bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Что именно мы будем?') забыл добавить reply_markup=markup, однако бот всё равно не реагирует на эту кнопку.

Comment: Вроде бы @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True) только на одну функцию вешается. То есть у вас переопределение обработчика происходит.

Comment: Вот это декоратор обрабатывает все коллбаки @bot.callback_query_handler

Comment: Как мне быть в таком случае?

Comment: Что именно должно произойти?

Comment: Бот должен ответить "что именно будем"?

Comment: При условии, что человек выбирает "Первое блюдо", бот должен перекидывать на другое меню (второй@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)). Но ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Как то так нужно*

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    async def callback(call):
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'Yes1':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
                itemFirstBut = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Первое блюдо ', callback_data='1Dish')
                itemSecondBut = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Второе блюдо ', callback_data='2Dish')
                itemDrinksBut = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Напитки ☕️', callback_data='Drinks')
                itemBackBut = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Я передумал..', callback_data='Back')
                markup.add(itemFirstBut, itemSecondBut, itemDrinksBut, itemBackBut)
                await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Тогда давайте выбирать!', reply_markup=markup)
            if call.data == 'No1':
                await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, ':(')

            if call.data == '1Dish':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
                itemSup1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Том Ям', callback_data='Tom Yan')
                itemSup2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Ливанский суп', callback_data='Livanskie')
                itemSup3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Тыквенный суп', callback_data='Tikveniy')
                itemSup4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Борщ с говядиной', callback_data='Borch')
                itemSup5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Фо Бо', callback_data='Fo Bo')
                markup.add(itemSup1, itemSup2, itemSup3, itemSup4, itemSup5)
                await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Что именно мы будем?')
```

Comment: if elif if elif